# Sphinx Search diferent code diferent results

Tags: php, sphinx

I have a products table:

```
id, code, name, groups, price
1   C001  Name1 71,71,209, 10
2   C002  Name2 76,77,221, 31
3   C003  Name3 171,437,2541, 50
```

When I'm trying to fetch result using code below, everything works:

```
$s->ResetFilters();
$s->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED);
$s->SetLimits($page, 20);
$products = $s->query('@groups 71|77', 'products');
```

I get right results: ID: 1 and 2;

I don't understand why this code doesn't work:

```
$s->ResetFilters();
$s->SetLimits($page, 20);
$s->SetSelect("*");
$s->SetFilter('groups', array(71,77));
$products = $s->query('','products');
```

In this case I have wrong products and "groups" field in "attrs" array everytime empty.

And another question: how can I find "min" and "max" price from result without limit instruction:

```
$s->SetLimits($page, 20);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Attributes and full-text fields are different things in Sphinx. query() is for doing full-text search and as long as "groups" is a full-text field you can use it there. If you want to make "groups" an attribute you need to:

1. define it as an attribute in your config using sql_attr_uint,
   rt_attr_uint, rt_attr_multi or smth else depending on the type of
   that
2. use SetFilter to filter by the attribute.

To find "min" and "max" price you can do

```
$cl->SetSelect('*,min(price),max(price)');
```

P.S. I recommend you use SphinxQL since it has wider functionality, for most that's easier to understand and program.